# Photo replaces when save to Directory

Tags: ios, directory, save

I am using the code

```
NSArray *directoryNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hats",@"bottoms",@"right",@"left",nil];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder

    for (int i = 0; i < [directoryNames count] ; i++) {
        NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[directoryNames objectAtIndex:i]];
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil]; //Create folder

        NSString *folderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"hats"]; // "right" is at index 2, per comments & code
        NSString *filePath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"IMAGE_NAME_HERE.PNG"]; 
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(captureImage.image);
        [imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }
```

to save however it always replaces itself so I can't save multiple photo's.  How should I make it so that it will stop doing that without duplicating itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're always saving to the same place, per this code:

```
NSString *folderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"hats"]; // "right" is at index 2, per comments & code
        NSString *filePath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"IMAGE_NAME_HERE.PNG"]; 
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(captureImage.image);
        [imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Looping through the array just saves everything to the 'hats' path every time.  You're already calculating the place to store the image based on the array object, through the dataPath object.  You just aren't doing anything with that.  Instead, do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [directoryNames count] ; i++) {
        NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[directoryNames objectAtIndex:i]];
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil]; //Create folder
        [imageData writeToFile:dataPath atomically:YES];
    }
```